# No module named 'Pillow'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I am using Spyder to run a sample code from Kera's doc
https://keras.io/examples/mnist_denoising_autoencoder/
Because PIL is deprecated.I changed the line #15

from PIL import image

into

from Pillow import image

Yet I was prompted that 
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow''

I reinstalled everything including re-establishing an environment. By using pip list, Pillow has been installed, versioned 5.4.1

I have also noticed that I have installed image,
yet as I tried to use

import image

A message 
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image''
appeared.

May anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's `Image` not `image`. What's the error report for `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: Bro, what is your python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the package is called Pillow, not the module you use in your source.
You still have to use

```
from PIL import Image
```

If you have Pillow installed and not PIL, this will use Pillow

Comment: Thanks, but I rechecked what I had installed by conda list, there IS a pillow versioned 6.0.0 (lower-cased p). I tried but failed with the same message. If I tried to install PIL, it said that many modules will be downgraded into python2.7 (I am using python3.7 now). So in fact neither upper- or lower-cased pillow works. Any idea?

Comment: @Theron You have to ***INSTALL*** pillow but then you ***IMPORT*** PIL

Comment: I see. The strange thing is that if I enter conda list it shows: pillow 6.0.0, yet if I enter pip list, it shows Pillow (capital letter) 6.0.0. Is there any difference btw them? Also (I am a rookie to Python, anyway) what is the difference when I install modules using conda install and pip install in my environment built up in Anaconda? Anyway, the original problem has been solved in your way, thanks a lot!!! :-)